# How to print (using cout) a number in binary form?

Tags: c++, binary, iostream, representation, std-bitset

I'm following a college course about operating systems and we're learning how to convert from binary to hexadecimal, decimal to hexadecimal, etc. and today we just learned how signed/unsigned numbers are stored in memory using the two's complement (~number + 1).

We have a couple of exercises to do on paper and I would like to be able to verify my answers before submitting my work to the teacher. I wrote a C++ program for the first few exercises but now I'm stuck as to how I could verify my answer with the following problem:

```
char a, b;

short c;
a = -58;
c = -315;

b = a >> 3;
```

and we need to show the binary representation *in memory* of `a`, `b` and `c`.

I've done it on paper and it gives me the following results (all the binary representations in memory of the numbers after the two's complement):

> a = 00111010 (it's a char, so 1 byte)
>
> b = 00001000 (it's a char, so 1 byte)
>
> c = 11111110 11000101 (it's a short, so 2 bytes)

Is there a way to verify my answer? Is there a standard way in C++ to show the binary representation in memory of a number, or do I have to code each step myself (calculate the two's complement and then convert to binary)? I know the latter wouldn't take so long but I'm curious as to if there is a standard way to do so.

Comment: do you understand hexadecimal representation? if you do, you can print the hex representation  (using the `std::hex`) manipulator - I'll leave it as an exercise for you to work out the rest...

Comment: You emphasize "in memory" a lot, but I hope they're not making you deal with endian issues.

Comment: Do you know have any idea about what endianness is? If you do, do you care about it for this exercise? The answer to these questions may influence the answer to your question.

Comment: Depending on your IDE, if you are just looking to verify correctness of your hand-written solution and not actually writing a program to display something useful, you could use something like Visual Studio's memory viewer to view the exact contents of memory.

Comment: The Windows calculator does that for you. If you're not on Windows, I'm sure other operating systems come with such a thing, too.

Comment: Even Google does this, for instance [“-58 in binary”](http://www.google.com/search?q=-58%20in%20binary) – but +1 for wanting to find out how to do it yourself in code.

Comment: Even at a glance, all those numbers look wrong. `-58` is negative, so I immediately know the first bit should be a `1`, but your answer has the first bit `0`. And `00111010` right shifted 3 bits is `000 00111`, no math involved, so that answer is wrong too.

Answer (score 579, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create an [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) representing the value, then stream that to `cout`.

```
#include <bitset>
...

char a = -58;
std::bitset<8> x(a);
std::cout << x << '\n';

short c = -315;
std::bitset<16> y(c);
std::cout << y << '\n';
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but will this only show the binary representation of a number (e.g. 8 would be 00001000) or its memory representation (e.g. how -8 would be stored by taking care of the sign bit and using the "two's complement")?

Comment: @Jesse: `bitset`'s constructor argument is interpreted as an unsigned value, which works out the same as two's complement. Strictly speaking, C++ does not guarantee two's complement arithmetic, and also the `-58 >> 3` operation in your example is undefined.

Comment: Can I typecast the bitset value (i.e, x or y in this example) to a char*?

Comment: @nirvanaswap: I suppose you can cast it, but the result is unlikely to be useful. If you need the result as a string, use `bitset`'s `to_string` member.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I discovered to_string minutes later. FYI, casting doesn't work, the bitset variable is an object of some really arcane-looking bitset3ul (?!) class. Best to let the abstractions do the work!

Comment: how to do it in C? Also i want to ask when does 2's complment perform , for exmaple if i write unsigned int a = 2 and when signed int a = 2 , do the signed one store 2 as 2's complement `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101` or does it gets stored in usual way `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010` . what is the deciding factor of whether to perform 2's complement or not? This question is bugging me for a while.

Comment: How to separate bytes when printing the bits?

Comment: Okay nevermind; I've tried getting the bit-string through `bitset::to_string()` then used [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458653/8524922) to separate by a space every 8 bits: **`separate<8, ' '>(s);`**

Comment: `std::cout << std::bitset<8>(a); << std::endl` is a nice one liner

Answer (score 167):

Use on-the-fly conversion to `std::bitset`. No temporary variables, no loops, no functions, no macros.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb4d6c10f8fe595d)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    int a = -58, b = a>>3, c = -315;

    std::cout << "a = " << std::bitset<8>(a)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << std::bitset<8>(b)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << std::bitset<16>(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
a = 11000110
b = 11111000
c = 1111111011000101
```

Comment: Note that hard-coding size is not necessary.  E.g. to print `x` use: `std::cout << std::bitset<8*sizeof(x)>(x)`.

Answer (score 80):

In C++20 you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
unsigned char a = -58;
std::cout << std::format("{:b}", a);
```

Output:

```
11000110
```

On older systems you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YK4nKK)):

```
unsigned char a = -58;
fmt::print("{:b}", a);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Comment: `std::format` is not yet available in Visual Studio 2019, is it?

Comment: @rturrado `std::format` is available in Visual Studio 2019. You have to `#include <format>` and set `/std:c++latest`.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to display the bit representation of any object, not just an integer, remember to reinterpret as a char array first, then you can print the contents of that array, as hex, or even as binary (via bitset):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
void show_binrep(const T& a)
{
    const char* beg = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);
    const char* end = beg + sizeof(a);
    while(beg != end)
        std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT>(*beg++) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    char a, b;
    short c;
    a = -58;
    c = -315;
    b = a >> 3;
    show_binrep(a);
    show_binrep(b);
    show_binrep(c);
    float f = 3.14;
    show_binrep(f);
}
```

Note that most common systems are little-endian, so the output of `show_binrep(c)` is **not** the 1111111 011000101 you expect, because that's not how it's stored in memory. If you're looking for *value* representation in binary, then a simple `cout << bitset<16>(c)` works.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a standard way in C++ to show the binary representation in memory of a number [...]?

No. There's no `std::bin`, like `std::hex` or `std::dec`, but it's not hard to output a number binary yourself:

You output the left-most bit by masking all the others, left-shift, and repeat that for all the bits you have.

(The number of bits in a type is `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT`.)

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what is already posted, just using bit-shift and mask to get the bit; usable for any type, being a template (<s>only not sure if there is a standard way to get number of bits in 1 byte, I used 8 here</s>).

```
#include<iostream>
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
void printBin(const T& t){
    size_t nBytes=sizeof(T);
    char* rawPtr((char*)(&t));
    for(size_t byte=0; byte<nBytes; byte++){
        for(size_t bit=0; bit<CHAR_BIT; bit++){
            std::cout<<(((rawPtr[byte])>>bit)&1);
        }
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
};

int main(void){
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
        std::cout<<i<<": ";
        printBin(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard way to get the number of bits per byte is the macro `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: It appears that sbi edited the post of Εύδοξος according to @R.MartinhoFernandes's comment. However, he didn't change the last sentence. I will edit.

Answer (score 4):

**Reusable function:**

```
template<typename T>
static std::string toBinaryString(const T& x)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::bitset<sizeof(T) * 8>(x);
    return ss.str();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int main(){
  uint16_t x=8;
  std::cout << toBinaryString(x);
}
```

This works with all kind of integers.

Answer (score 2):

Using the std::bitset answers and convenience templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
struct BinaryForm {
    BinaryForm(const T& v) : _bs(v) {}
    const std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT> _bs;
};

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BinaryForm<T>& bf) {
    return os << bf._bs;
}
```

Using it like this:

```
auto c = 'A';
std::cout << "c: " << c << " binary: " << BinaryForm{c} << std::endl;
unsigned x = 1234;
std::cout << "x: " << x << " binary: " << BinaryForm{x} << std::endl;
int64_t z { -1024 };
std::cout << "z: " << z << " binary: " << BinaryForm{z} << std::endl;
```

Generates output:

```
c: A binary: 01000001
x: 1234 binary: 00000000000000000000010011010010
z: -1024 binary: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem when playing competitive coding games online. Here is a solution that is quick to implement and is fairly intuitive. It also avoids outputting leading zeros or relying on `<bitset>`

```cpp
std::string s;
do {
    s = std::to_string(r & 1) + s;
} while ( r>>=1 );

std::cout << s;
```

You should note however that this solution will increase your runtime, so if you are competing for optimization or not competing at all you should use one of the other solutions on this page.

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for "prints in binary WHILE avoiding outputting leading zeros"

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>       // in order to use pow() function
using namespace std; 

string show_binary(unsigned int u, int num_of_bits);

int main() 
{ 

  cout << show_binary(128, 8) << endl;   // should print 10000000
  cout << show_binary(128, 5) << endl;   // should print 00000
  cout << show_binary(128, 10) << endl;  // should print 0010000000

  return 0; 
}

string show_binary(unsigned int u, int num_of_bits) 
{ 
  string a = "";

  int t = pow(2, num_of_bits);   // t is the max number that can be represented

  for(t; t>0; t = t/2)           // t iterates through powers of 2
      if(u >= t){                // check if u can be represented by current value of t
          u -= t;
          a += "1";               // if so, add a 1
      }
      else {
          a += "0";               // if not, add a 0
      }

  return a ;                     // returns string
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt' it be `int t = pow(2, num_of_bits - 1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using old C++ version, you can use this snippet :

```
template<typename T>
string toBinary(const T& t)
{
  string s = "";
  int n = sizeof(T)*8;
  for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    s += (t & (1 << i))?"1":"0";
  }
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  char a, b;

  short c;
  a = -58;
  c = -315;

  b = a >> 3;

  cout << "a = " << a << " => " << toBinary(a) << endl;
  cout << "b = " << b << " => " << toBinary(b) << endl;
  cout << "c = " << c << " => " << toBinary(c) << endl;
}

a = => 11000110
b = => 11111000
c = -315 => 1111111011000101
```

Comment: Printing the wrong number of bits. 111 000 110 is 9 bits, not 8.

Comment: I made boundary mistake , please check now

Answer (score -5):

Here is the true way to get binary representation of a number:

```
unsigned int i = *(unsigned int*) &x;
```

Comment: No ; this just copies x into i. Unless you meant this as a joke?

Answer (score -13):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
std::cout << std::hex << val << std::endl;
```

Comment: **Moderator Note** I _tried_ to purge antagonistic or otherwise non constructive comments under this answer selectively, and I ended up with a very broken conversation. All comments were purged. Please keep comments professional, constructive and most of all on topic. If the OP wanted to remove this, the OP would have removed it by now. If you disagree with this answer, then vote. If you can improve this answer, edit. `</argument>`. Really, we're adults, yes? I almost checked the ages on all that commented here to make sure everyone was over 13.