# simple change of a character to its bit representation

Tags: c++, bitset, std-bitset

Why am I getting an error? It looks pretty straightforward to me. Also, is this the best method for doing what I'm trying to do?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>


int main() { 

char j = "J"; 
std::cout << bitchar(j);
return 0; 
} 


std::string bitchar(char c) { 
  std::string s;
  unsigned thisdivisor = (unsigned)c;
  while (!thisdivisor) { 
      s += thisdivisor % 2 ? '0' : '1';
      thisdivisor /= 2;
  }
  return s; 
}
```

Comment: Be more specific with your problem. What kind of an error are you getting?

Comment: `'J'` for char. Also the bits are negated: `%2 ? 0:1`. And reversed in order.

Comment: First, it should be `char j = 'J'; `

Comment: There is a problem with your algorithm.  Use test case value 'I', 0x49, 0100 1001.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

int main() {   
    char j = 'J'; 
    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(j);
    return 0;  
}
```

Note:

1. `"J"` is a single character C-style string(with a trailing `\0`),
   you should use `'J'` for `char`.
2. Use `std::bitset` to print the bit pattern.

Comment: If he's trying to learn the underlying mechanism, telling him to use a predefined class doesn't really help him. It's like giving a calculator to a child instead of teaching them how to add and multiply.

Comment: @Barmar I got your point, but since he also asked if his method is the best, I guess my answer can be useful to him, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try `char j = 'j'` instead of `="j"` to assign a character to your variable. "j" is a string array.

Comment: Whoops. My bad on the j assignment. Didn't see that for some reason.

Comment: Great, speedy answer, gave creds in my extended version

Answer (score 2):

### Answer 1: Why am I getting these errors

Try `char j = 'J'`, as said by @losifM. The double-quote defines a character array, and you're looking for a single character (single quote).

### Answer 2: What's a better way

A better way to do such a thing would be using an `std::bitset`, then stream it using `cout`.

```
//Add this
#include <bitset>

char j = 'j';
std::bitset<8> x(j);
std::cout << x;
```

Should be self explanatory at that point, but this may help: [How to print (using cout) the way a number is stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349689/c-how-to-print-using-cout-the-way-a-number-is-stored-in-memory)

### Sidenote:

```
  s += thisdivisor % 2 ? '0' : '1';
```

should also be

```
  s += thisdivisor % 2 ? '1' : '0';
```

because if `thisdivisor % 2` returns `1` (`true`), you want it to add `1` to s, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to describe the error. Presumably it's something like

```
‘bitchar’ was not declared in this scope
```

because you didn't declare the function before you called it in `main`. Either move the definition of `bitchar` before `main`, or add a declaration before or inside `main`:

```
std::string bitchar(char c);
```

Then you'll probably get something like:

```
invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’
```

because you're trying to assign a string literal `"J"` to a character variable. Use a character literal `'J'` (with single quotes) instead.

Then you'll find you're not getting any output. That's because `while (!thisdivisor)` loops as long as the value is zero; so it won't loop at all if you give it a non-zero value. You want `while (thisdivisor)` (or `while (thisdiviser != 0)` if you want to be more explicit), to loop while it's *not* zero.

Then you'll find that the bits are inverted; you want '0' if the modulo result is zero, while your test gives '0' if it is *not* zero:

```
s += thisdivisor % 2 ? '1' : '0';
```

or

```
s += (thisdivisor % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';
```

Finally, you might want to reverse the string (or build it by prepending rather than appending) to get the more conventional most-significant-bit-first ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning char array (which decay to pointer) to char (J). 
And then you initialize std::string with char (should be c-string).