# How to insert a character every N characters in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

How can I insert a **char**acter into a **string** exactly after 1 character?

I need to insert '|' into
the string after every other character.

In other words (C++): `"Tokens all around!"`
Turns into: `"T|o|k|e|n|s| |a|l|l| |a|r|o|u|n|d|!"` (no thats not an array)

Thanks

Comment: id create a new string that is twice the size. copy a character, insert |, rinse & repeat.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I am making a programming language that doesn't compile, but users will be able to make compilers with it because it will be advanced. By saying: 'it will not compile', I mean you write a program in a file and drag and drop it onto a exe and you see the output in cmd.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I made it :) It transforms into C and then it uses MinGW to handle the rest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::string tokenize(const std::string& s) {
   if (!s.size()) {
     return "";
   }
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << s[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++) {
     ss << '|' << s[i];
   }
   return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd use a standard algorithm and iterator:

```
std::string add_seps(std::string const &input, std::string sep="|") { 
    std::ostringstream os;
    std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(os, sep));
    return os.str();
}
```

As it stands, this adds a separator after the last character of the input. If you only want them between characters, you'd use an [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

Comment: Does this answer the question in the title, every Nth character? Can the iterator be rewritten to handle that?

Comment: @Jonny: It inserts a separator after each "item" in the input. Since it turned out he wanted it after every character, this just uses an "item" of type char. If you wanted 2 characters, then a separator, you'd copy two-character strings from input to output.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my C++11 example (with gcc 4.7):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<const unsigned num, const char separator>
void separate(std::string & input)
{
    for ( auto it = input.begin(); (num+1) <= std::distance(it, input.end()); ++it )
    {
        std::advance(it,num);
        it = input.insert(it,separator);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string input{"aaffbb3322ff77c"};
    separate<3,' '>(input);
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    separate<4,'+'>(input);
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result output is:

aaf fbb 332 2ff 77c

aaf +fbb +332 +2ff +77c

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string& insert (size_t pos, const string& str);
```

You would have to loop through the string, inserting a character each time.

```
for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i++) {
      str << str.insert(i, '|');
      i++;
}
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can actually show me the code you would write.

Comment: @IdealHate solution is probably the best

Comment: @mgreenier did you vote it up? as it all comes to people voting not saying.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach that will only do 1 allocation for the resultant string so it should be slightly more efficient than some other suggestions.

```
std::string AddSeparators(const std::string & s)
{
    if(s.size() <= 1)
        return s;

    std::string r;
    r.reserve((s.size()*2)-1);
    r.push_back(s[0]);
    for(size_t i = 1; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        r.push_back('|');
        r.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
```