# Insert a character every N characters in a string in C++ changing N character

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to use:

```
std::string tokenize(const std::string& s) {
   if (!s.size()) {
     return "";
   }
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << s[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++) { // tried i++ ----> i+=16
     ss << '|' << s[i];
   }
   return ss.str();
}
```

from ([How to insert a character every N characters in a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952032/how-to-insert-a-character-every-n-characters-in-a-string-in-c)) but changing the `"|"` inserted from every one character to every 16 characters.

I tried changing `i++` ----> `i+=16` but that fails and makes `"sqdfqdfqwerqwer"` become `"s|q"`

Can someone find my error?

Comment: Are you new to `for` loops?

Comment: Yes. I just started C++ a few days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i+=16) { // tried i++ ----> i+=16

     ss << '|' << s[i];
   }
```

**firstly:**

> but that fails and makes `"sqdfqdfqwerqwer"` become `"s|q"`

You are jumping from 1st position(`i=1`) to 16th position(`i+=16`) of the given string directly.i.e when loop runs second time the postion is in `1+16`th postion.

so `ss` is getting string `s[0],s[i],s[i+16],s[2i+16]...`
that is why you are getting stripped down version of string s.

**Solution**
it is rather simple which is already answered above

```
for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++) {
     if (i%16==0) ss << '|'; <<-- this is the main concept you are missing
     ss << s[i];
   }
```

- We loop through all of the characters of the string
- check if we are in required position. for more information for see how Modulo operator works.
- if we get the required position do what you want to do.

**Now when i pass**

`DoesThisAnswerYourQuestion?ImGladItDid.IfNotITriedMybest:D`

**it prints out**

`DoesThisAnswerYo|urQuestion?ImGla|dItDid.IfNotITri|edMybest:D`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++) {
     if (i%16==0) ss << '|';
     ss << s[i];
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the error is?  I think the question is asking that.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried changing i++ ----> i+=16 but that fails and makes
>   "sqdfqdfqwerqwer" become "s|q"

The error is that you increment by 16. You put put the first character into the stream. Then you loop once and put `|` and the next character into the stream. Then you increment by 16, which leads to `i` being larger than the size of the string. Thus the loop exits and the mentioned result prints out.

@kirbyfan64os suggested a correction. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Walking through,

```
ss << s[0];
```

First character goes into the output stream

```
for (int i = 1;
```

Starting at 1

```
     i < s.size();
```

and continuing until you reach or pass the end of the string

```
     i++)
```

look at each element in the array

```
    ss << '|' << s[i];
```

put a | and the current character into the output stream.

So for "ABC" The loop unrolls to:

```
ss << A;      //ss << s[0];
ss << | << B; //ss << '|' << s[1];
ss << | << C; //ss << '|' << s[2];
```

Stream contents are A|B|C

```
for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i+=16)
```

Means look at the second element and every 16th element after in the string. In other words, s[1], s[17], s[33], s[49]...

So for "sqdfqdfqwerqwer" you unroll to:

```
ss << s;      //ss << s[0];
ss << | << q; //ss << '|' << s[1];
```

And there are only 15 characters in the string, so there is no 17 to look at. Output is:

```
s|q
```

Just as the OP noted.

OK. Screwed that up last time, so take two. This can be done without the string buffer by concatenating strings, but the stringstream is probably the quicker choice. I'd have to profile to prove that, though. I've also made a quick tweak to allow the caller to specify the length. It was useful for testing, so I left it in.

```
std::string tokenize(const std::string& s,
                     size_t where)
{
    if (s.size() > 0)
    {
        std::stringstream temp;
        temp << s.substr(0,where);
        for (size_t loc = where; loc < s.size(); loc+=where)
        {
            temp << '|' << s.substr(loc,where);
        }
        return temp.str();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Results:

```
In =  "I'm the very model of a modern major general" 
Out = "I'm the very mod|el of a modern m|ajor general"
```

Comment: your proposed solution is overwriting characters instead of inserting them in between characters.

Comment: Took a bit more than a moment, but I made sure this time. Actually, one thing I don't know is if the insert was to go before or after. Went with after.