# Converting integer to a sizable vector or string

Tags: c++

I am converting a decimal integer into a binary without using strings (in Visual Studio 2013):

```
int de2bi(int de)
{
int bi = 0, pos = 1;
while(de > 0)
{
    bi = bi + (de % 2) * pos;
    de = de / 2;
    pos *= 10;
}
return bin;
}
```

This way, the binary representation in output is actually a decimal number. The problem is that I want to control the number of digits in my binary output i.e. instead of 0 I want 00 or instead of 1 I want 01.

How can I convert the output into a vector/string with an appropriate size so that when converting decimal number '1', I can have '001' or '0001' in the returned output, depending on how many digits I need in my output?

Edit: I adopted the code from the answer down below. But it did not change the length of the output vector 'bin' in my code. It only prints '000' on the screen.

```
std::cout<<std::setw(3)<<std::setfill('0')<<bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string de2bi(int de){
    std::string bin = "";
    if( de == 0 ){
        return "0";
    }
    else if( de < 0 ){
        return "";
    }

    while(de){
        bin = std::to_string(de % 2) + bin ;
        de = de / 2;
    }
    return bin; 
}
```

you can test at here http://cpp.sh/5cx

Comment: @ Mr Jerry, thank you. I am using std::string in = de2bi(3); and I want to see printf("%s ", in[0]); or printf("%s ", in[1]); How do I access them?

Comment: in case de===0 I don't necessarily want to return 0 but depending on the desirable size in my code I might want 00 or 000 or 0000.

Comment: you can use ``printf("%c ", in[1])``

Comment: Yes that works for de2bi(3), but what if I want to convert decimals from 0 to 3 i.e. I want 00, 01, 10, 11 instead of 0, 1, 10, 11? How to generate that zero msb? I want to control the size of my returned string.

Comment: can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Having called your `de2bi` function, you can display the result `n` as a `w`-character wide output as follows:

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::setw(w) << std::setfill('0') << n;
```

For example, if `w` is `3` and `n` is `1` you'll get `001`.

There are many other S.O. questions and answers with more direct ways to display a number in binary, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349689/c-how-to-print-using-cout-the-way-a-number-is-stored-in-memory).

Comment: for some reason I cannot use the << operator. I receive error: no operator "<<" matches those operands operand types are: std::ostream<<void. Can you write without cout and <<? I want the returned vector to be of size w.

Comment: @Elnaz hmmm... did you also `#include <iostream>`?  If not - sorry for not mentioning it - I took that for granted.  You shouldn't try to avoid `std::cout`... it's best practice in C++.  If you're still having trouble, please post your exact code as an edit to your question and I'll happily take a look.  Cheers.

Comment: I use std::string number=de2bi(0); Then I want to for example have my number to be 000 instead of just 0. I'm printf("%c", number[1]). The above comment was my mistake. But again using your line of code above did not change the length of n from 1 to 3.

Comment: I want to actually have a vector of length 3 instead of just the display.

Comment: @Elnaz: *"std::string number=de2bi(0);"* the `de2bi` function in your question did not return a `std::string`.  My suggestion above is an alternative to "Mr Jerry"'s - not things you can combine.

Comment: BTW regarding *"it did not change the length of the output vector 'bin' in my code. It only prints '000' on the screen."* - `bin` in your code is an `int`... a number without any particular output representation... it's not an "output vector".  You have to decide on the output format *each time* you output it to the screen, a file etc...  If you want to capture that representation as a `std::string`, use `#include <sstream>` followed by `std::ostringstream oss; oss << std::setw(w) << std::setfill('0') << n; std::string representation = oss.str();`

Comment: I meant after switching to Mr Jerry's. Then the bin is returned as std::string. It's just that it does not include the msb zeros. I wanted to use an additional code to sort of pre-fill bin with necessary zeros.

Comment: @Elnaz: well, you can just say `while (bin.size() < width) bin = '0' + bin;`