# How do I write binary data to a file in Modern C++?

Tags: c++11

Writing binary data to a file in C is simple: use fwrite, passing the address of the object you want to write and the size of the object.  Is there something more "correct" for Modern C++ or should I stick to using FILE* objects?  As far as I can tell the IOStream library is for writing formatted data rather than binary data, and the write member asks for a char* leaving me littering my code with casts.

Comment: You use the [`std::basic_ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) and [`std::basic_istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) functions to write or read e.g. structures or other binary/raw data. And yes, you have to do type-casting to make it work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this should be an answer.

Comment: These  casts are a friendly reminder that *you are reinterpreting your data as a sequence of bytes*. If you don't like the litter, wrap `read` and `write` such that te wrappers accept `void*` rather than `char*`, and add error handling while you're at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349689/c-how-to-print-using-cout-the-way-a-number-is-stored-in-memory

Comment: See [this mine answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28748914/841108) to a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the game here is to enable argument dependent lookup on reading and writing, and make sure you don't try to read/write things that are not flat data.

It fails to catch data containing pointers, which also should not be read/written this way, but it is better than nothing

```
namespace serialize {
  namespace details {
    template<class T>
    bool write( std::streambuf& buf, const T& val ) {
      static_assert( std::is_standard_layout<T>{}, "data is not standard layout" );
      auto bytes = sizeof(T);
      return buf.sputn(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val), bytes) == bytes;
    }
    template<class T>
    bool read( std::streambuf& buf, T& val ) {
      static_assert( std::is_standard_layout<T>{}, "data is not standard layout" );
      auto bytes = sizeof(T);
      return buf.sgetn(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), bytes) == bytes;
    }
  }
  template<class T>
  bool read( std::streambuf& buf, T& val ) {
    using details::read; // enable ADL
    return read(buf, val);
  }
  template<class T>
  bool write( std::streambuf& buf, T const& val ) {
    using details::write; // enable ADL
    return write(buf, val);
  }
}

namespace baz {
    // plain old data:
    struct foo {int x;};
    // not standard layout:
    struct bar {
      bar():x(3) {}
      operator int()const{return x;}
      void setx(int s){x=s;}
      int y = 1;
    private:
      int x;
    };
    // adl based read/write overloads:
    bool write( std::streambuf& buf, bar const& b ) {
        bool worked = serialize::write( buf, (int)b );
        worked = serialize::write( buf, b.y ) && worked;
        return worked;
    }
    bool read( std::streambuf& buf, bar& b ) {
        int x;
        bool worked = serialize::read( buf, x );
        if (worked) b.setx(x);
        worked = serialize::read( buf, b.y ) && worked;
        return worked;
    }
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49dfd60320ca4fbd).

Possibly you should restrict said writing based off `is_pod` not standard layout, with the idea that if something special should happen on construction/destruction, maybe you shouldn't be binary blitting the type.

Comment: That's looking good, but before I accept, can you tell me why you have declared a forwarding function?

Comment: @hatcat easy ADL.  Call `serialize::read` explicitly and it will still find a local namespace `read` override for a type.  Easier than forcing end users to always be ADL friendly when calling `read`, so I did the work for them.

Comment: @hatcat as an aside, have a not standard layout sfinae tested `std::tuple<Ts&...>` overload in details.  Then aggregates can `read(stream,std::tie(my_members...))` and poof, done.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already bypassing all formatting, I would recommend using the [`std::filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) class directly to avoid possible overheads from `std::fstream`; it's definitely better than `FILE*` due to RAII.

You can't escape from the casts this way, sadly. But it's not hard to wrap it, like:

```
template<class T>
void write(std::streambuf& buf, const T& val)
{
    std::size_t to_write = sizeof val;
    if (buf.sputn(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val), to_write) != to_write)
        // do some error handling here
}
```