# How are doubles represented when written to text files?

Tags: c++, file, format, double

When you write a number of doubles to a file, in which format are they stored? Is it in byte format or string format?

E.g. given 0.00083231. Is it stored with 10 bytes, where each byte represents one digit? Or is it stored as only 8 bytes, since the size of a double is 8 bytes?

Assume that the language used is C++.

Comment: That depends on what method you used to write it.

Comment: It could be either of those, or something completely different. It all depends on *how* you write it to the file.

Comment: The format could be literally anything. Is there a specific case you are asking about?

Comment: your question doesnt make sense. When written to a text file doubles are in the format you say they are in. I think you are asking about how they are written to a binary file. In that case its as a plain memory dump of the double.

Comment: "Try it and see" isn't always the best advice--because sometimes, you try something on one machine and it will be different on another...it may be platform sensitive, or vary by compiler, etc.   But in this case, trying it and showing what you attempted would be good research for refining the question.  *("is it always like this...guaranteed? what if I wanted it to be different? etc.)*

Comment: it would be best for you to shows us the code you are using to write the double to the file

Comment: Do you mean a straight write as a double in whatever exponent, magnitude format your compiler uses to perform the operations or did you specify a string or BCD in your output?

Comment: You can do anything you put your mind to!

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to write text, e.g. with formatted output like `file << x`, you get text.

If you choose to write bytes, e.g. with unformatted output like `file.write(&x, sizeof x)`, you get bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> When you write a number of doubles to a file, in which format are they stored? Is it in byte format or string format?

It depends on which functions you use to write the numbers.

E.g.:

If you use `fprintf` or `printf`, the number will be written out in textual form, which, in your example, will be written as `0.000832` with the format `"%lf"` and will take 8 bytes. You can change the format to change the number of bytes used to write out the number. The resulting output will be in human readable form. Same thing if you use `cout << number;`.

If you use `fwrite`, the number will be written in binary form. The number of bytes necessary to store the number will always be `sizeof(double)` regardless of the value of the number. The resulting output will not be human readable. Same  thing if you use `ostream::write`.

Comment: by default the printed value is `0.000832` with 6 decimal places, which takes 8 bytes

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you print the value

If you print the number as a binary value, it'll take `sizeof(double)` bytes (which is not always 8) in the file and you can't read the value with a normal text viewer/editor. You must use a binary/hex editor to see it in binary format.

If you print the number using a text output function, the result depends on how you format it. If you use `cout` or functions in `std::printf` family using `%f` format, the value will be printed using **6 significant digits** so it'll take only 8 bytes in textual format at most. If you use a different length/width specifier (for example `printf("%9.10f\n", 0.00083231)` then of course the real bytes printed will be different. Using another format will also result in different printed form outputs. For example `%e`  will print out the string in the scientific format which is `8.323100e-04` in your case, and take at least 12 bytes in the output string. `%a` will print out the value in hexadecimal form which will be even longer except for values that are exactly representable in binary. See live example [here](http://ideone.com/bsPoFS)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you write them. You could use [std::ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) and its (overloaded) `operator <<`; then they are stored in textual form. You could use binary IO e.g. [std::ostream::write](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) or `fwrite` then they are stored in native machine binary form.

You probably should read more about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), and consider using textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/) (e.g. with [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/)). You might be interested by binary serialization e.g. [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) or [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation)

Notice that data is often more important than code, and that disk IO or network IO is a lot (e.g. many thousand times at least) slower than CPU. So spending CPU times to make the data easier to store is often worthwhile. Also, the same data could be written on one machine, and read on some very different one.

Read also about [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29), [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/270054/40065).