# I would like to learn about how to read a .dat file

Tags: c++

I have a dat file that is filled up with data formatted like:

```
HA 120
Barry Bonds
Home Run King
Giants Player
Legend
San Francisco
120
```

What would be the best way of reading this file to a temp variable so I can create a class instance with the variables from data line 1-7 as parameters(i know how to set them into parameter i just cannot figure out how to get the data from the file into my line variable). I have tried the ways to do it with a txt file but I believe thats not working due to the .dat being a binary file.

```
string line;
  cout << "starting to read user data \n";
  fstream file("baseball.dat");
  file.open("baseball.dat:", ios::binary);
  vector<course> tempList;
  if(!file.is_open()){
    cout << "error" << endl;
    
  }
    cout << "file is open \n";
    file >> line;
    cout << line << "\n";

//tried a different way to do it, still no work
    while(getline(file, line)){
      cout << "line is " << line << "\n";
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
```

Im not getting an error and the file is opening, the variables are just not populating when i go and print it

Help with figuring out how to read from a .dat file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ reading binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765881/c-reading-binary-files)

Comment: A ".dat" file could be *anything*. You cannot make assumptions based on the file extension alone. You can name a file anything you like, the name means nothing. Want to store a MS Word document in a file named "example.png"? Go right ahead, it's still a Word document, not an image, regardless of the name. You need to *parse* the *content* of a file to figure out its type - you cannot rely on just the name.

Comment: ok, so it is basically a .txt file hidden behind a .dat file extension? I already know what is in it(bunch of strings), so how do i now open that file and access the data? @JesperJuhl

Comment: "how do i now open that file and access the data?" - just like you would any other file.

Comment: @Filburt not really. In their case, they are using a png  "which (presumably) contains binary encoded image data (aka an array of red/green/blue intensity levels or some such stuff)." this is not the case for my issue, i have very easily readable data in a .dat file and would like to access that.

Comment: @JohnSnow `file.open("baseball.dat:", ios::binary);` -- Is this a text file?  If so, why are you opening it as binary?  And why the `:` at the end of the name?  Also, if the file can't be opened, your code goes on as if nothing is wrong.  Just printing a message saying the file can't be opened is not enough.

Comment: @JohnSnow The answer shows an example for reading "Hello world" from binary so it looks applicable to your problem for me.

Comment: There is no indication this is actually a file that requires to be opened in binary mode.  All that can be determined is that there are 7 lines of string data, and they can be easily read with 7 calls to `std::getline(file, somestring);`, and then process those 7 lines appropriately.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i took binary out when trying to open and fixed the name and went with something like this:
'
  getline(file, line);

  cout << line << endl;
'
still does not work.

Comment: `fstream file("baseball.dat"); file.open("baseball.dat:", ios::binary);` -- If you removed the `:`, your code is erroneously opening the file twice.  See [constructor (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).

Comment: Can you open the file in the text editor you use to write programs? When you do, does it look like text? Or does it look like a bunch of random characters (the binary part), mixed with some recognizable text? If it looks like text, then it is NOT a binary file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Mr.McKenzie, I cannot thank you enough for the help you have given me. Throughout different avenues we tried you stuck with the problem, and I thank you. I could not have gone ahead and figured this out without the help of your knowledge.

Comment: Please clarify your definition of *"best"*.  Sometimes using `std::getline` is good enough to get the task finished.  Sometimes, you'll want to use buffers, block reading and a secondary thread to efficiently read from a file.  If your OS supports it, *memory map* a file to treat it as a buffer is the best method, because you are delegating the reading to the operating system