# adding a digit at the end of a number, (not summing) in C++

Tags: c++

I already tried looking for this and they gave me to just do along the lines of:

```
int x = 1;
while (x != 11)
{
    x = x * 10 + (x+1);
}
cout<<x;

output: 12345678910
```

While this is good and all I have the problem that if the first number is a zero, it ignores that. so it would do

```
0 * 10 + (0+1)
```

which would come out to "1" not "01". Is there a good alternative way to add numbers together in this manner?

Comment: Use `std::string` for that

Comment: Displaying a leading 0 is a visualization problem.

Comment: 01 and 1 denote the same number though

Comment: Yeah but Im making a binary converter and some numbers start with 0, not 1

Comment: Also, literal numbers with leading zeros are interpreted to be in base 8. E.g. 0123 and 123 are not the same numbers and `0123==123` returns `false`.

Comment: You could use `std::bitset` and convert to a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349689/how-to-print-using-cout-the-way-a-number-is-stored-in-memory

Comment: @Sabishī -- `01` is `1` in binary.  So I don't know why a "binary converter" is anything special to consider.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I actually realized that my converter did the conversion in reverse so I have to reverse it. I got that all setup but now this is my problem that when a lot of numbers in binary like for example "2" in decimal is "10" in binary it would first give the system "01" but because of my code it gives "1".

Comment: Tbh the whole code is quite a mess but I was wondering if there was a way to do it like this instead of redoing the code so it converts the right way.

Comment: You can't convert while using an integer and keep the leading 0s in the int. if you are not permitted to use std::bitset do it using a string.

Comment: Then I guess i'll convert it into a string then.

Comment: Do you know how long your final number is going to be?

Comment: No, its for a binary converter so its up to the user to choose how long its going to be.

Comment: So the user is inputting something like "0110100101" to a console, and expecting to get the decimal equivalent as a response?

Comment: Well yeah, just the other way so a decimal to binary converter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you're trying to do, but it may help to think in terms of either *strings* or *numbers*. For a number there is no difference between 1 and 01, but for a string there is. So if the difference matters to you, use a string.

For example, you can simply use the `<<` operator to convert individual digits to strings as you go:

```
int x = 0;
while(x<11)
{
    cout << x;
    x++;
}
```

Output:

```
012345678910
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and I guess this would work but as I said in an earlier comment the final number still gets reversed after the while loop. Is there a way I could assign the final number to an int?

Comment: so I could declare like x = x + x+1 (but without summing x to x+1, rather adding it at the end of the number)

Comment: Sure. The "adding" operation you refer to is actually a "string concatenation". The `*10` trick is just that - a trick to perform actual string concatenation. To make it easier, just do: 1) integer addition, 2) integer to string conversion, 3) string concatenation, and finally 4) string to integer conversion. Try each of those steps - you'll find heaps of examples with the right keywords. If you get stuck, ask a new specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the case that bitsets are what you're looking for. In a very quick example...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int                  input;
   bitset<32>           result(0);   //32 bits in an int

   cin >> input;
   result = input;
   cout << result;

   return 0;
}
```