# What's c++11/14/17 equivalence to C function of ltoa/itoa?

Tags: c++, string, function, binary, integer

C++11/14/17 provides functions from string to int/long, but what about vice versa?

I wish to convert an integer to a binary string and then prints it, like:

```
int i = 127;
char buf[20];
ltoa(i, buf, 2);
printf("%032s\n", buf);
```

I can see

```
00000000000000000000000001111111
```

Currently I could only use C style function on different platforms, like on linux I've ltoa, on windows, _itoa_s (cannot be more ugly) ...

But what about c++?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `itoa()` and `ltoa()` are not part of standard C either.   In C, you will use functions like `sscanf()`.   In C++, you can use an  string stream  (`std::istringstream`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print (using cout) a number in binary form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349689/how-to-print-using-cout-a-number-in-binary-form)  `std::bitset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, we have `to_chars`:

```
int i = 127;
char buf[20];
auto [p, e] = std::to_chars(buf, buf + 20, i, 2);
```

The first two parameters are of type `char*` and denote the buffer.  The third parameter is the number.  The last parameter is the base.  This is essentially the same with `ltoa`.

`p` is the past-the-end pointer.  `e` is the error code.  Note that the string is not null-terminated.

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8SkuPNoInGbtHNQu))