# How to convert an unsigned integer into 32 bit binary representation

Tags: c++, binary

This is what I have for my conversion function so far
It takes an unsigned integer as a parameter.
It should give the result like

```
outputBinary(1) //=> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
outputBinary(5) //=> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
outputBinary(1000000) //=> 0000 0000 0000 1111 0100 0010 0100 0000
```

```
void outputBinary(unsigned int x){
  int temp = x;
  int remain;
  string binary = "";
  while(temp != 0){
    remain = temp%2;
    binary = binary + to_string(remain);
    temp = temp/2;
  }
  cout << binary << endl;
}
```

Comment: And your issue is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, for example to actually ask us a question.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me your problem is this outputs the bits in reverse order.

Comment: I'm wondering how to make this into a 32 bits binary representation, which takes account the zeros before it.

Comment: Hello, please write in your question what is the output you get from your code, and what is the output you want. It will help!

Comment: If you need 32 digits padded with zero, use a `for` loop to count to 32 instead of a while loop that stops when you're out of ones. If you want the digits in the correct order, flip the two sides of `+` on the line with `binary + to_string(remain)`.

Comment: When you have `std::bitset`, don't reinvent the wheel unless it's assignment. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349689/how-to-print-using-cout-a-number-in-binary-form

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want 32 bit representation, use uint32_t as type input for your function.

Secondly, instead of:

```
while(temp != 0){
    remain = temp%2;
    binary = binary + to_string(remain);
    temp = temp/2;
}
```

write something like

```
for(int i=0;i<32;++i){
    remain = temp%2;
    binary = to_string(remain).append(binary);
    temp = temp/2;
}
```

Of course this is not optimal. Instead i would suggest using something like bit shift operators and a char array with fixed size in which you just replace the character with 0 or 1 in the loop.

Comment: Thank you. And may I asked what does append do?

Comment: Well, initially binary is an empty string variable. At each step here, it is replaced by combination of new bit as a string and previous value. For example for 8 in binary, the values will change this way: 0, 0+0, 0+00, 1+000,0+1000,0+01000 and so on, where + is basically the apend operathor and the right part is the value from previous iteration of the string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the "leading" zero, you can't use `while(temp != 0){`. You'll have to make sure to loop exactly 32 times. A `for` loop can be used for this.

Further, use `uint32_t` to ensure that the input has 32 bits.

Like:

```
void outputBinary(uint32_t x){
  std::string binary = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
    if (i % 4 == 0) binary = " " + binary;
    binary = std::to_string(x % 2) + binary;
    x = x/2;
  }
  std::cout << binary << std::endl;
}
```

If called like `outputBinary(1000000);` the output is:

```
0000 0000 0000 1111 0100 0010 0100 0000
```

Comment: Thank you. That will help me a lot!